# Measure and Benchmark Time for Ruby Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, benchmarking, interpreter

How can i measure the time taken by a method and the individual statements in that method in Ruby. If you see the below method i want to measure the total time taken by the method and the time taken for database access and redis access. I do not want to write Benchmark.measure before every statement. Does the ruby interpreter gives us any hooks for doing this ?

```
def foo
# code to access database
# code to access redis. 
end
```

Comment: there is something similar to the `new Date()` of javascript that ruby has, but I can't remember the correct syntax. should give you a decent google listing though

Comment: @Phani Can you select a correct answer please? After 8 years, I think there are some solid answers here. Thanks.

Answer (score 154):

The simplest way:

```
require 'benchmark'

def foo
 time = Benchmark.measure do
  code to test
 end
 puts time.real #or save it to logs
end
```

Sample output:

```
2.2.3 :001 > foo
  5.230000   0.020000   5.250000 (  5.274806)
```

Values are: cpu time, system time, total and real elapsed time.

Source: [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html).

Comment: You can also do `Benchmark.realtime { block }` if you just want the realtime

Answer (score 137):

You could use the `Time` object. ([Time Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html))

For example,

```
start = Time.now
# => 2022-02-07 13:55:06.82975 +0100
# code to time
finish = Time.now
# => 2022-02-07 13:55:09.163182 +0100
diff = finish - start
# => 2.333432
```

`diff` would be in seconds, as a floating point number.

Comment: just a minor correction. `end` is reserved, so use some other variable name.

Comment: `Time.now` is affected by adjustments to the system clock, so it's a best practice to use `Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` instead. But for rough calculations this doesn't matter. https://blog.dnsimple.com/2018/03/elapsed-time-with-ruby-the-right-way/

Answer (score 61):

### Use `Benchmark`'s Report

```
require 'benchmark' # Might be necessary.

def foo
  Benchmark.bm( 20 ) do |bm|  # The 20 is the width of the first column in the output.
    bm.report( "Access Database:" ) do 
      # Code to access database.
    end
   
    bm.report( "Access Redis:" ) do
      # Code to access redis.
    end
  end
end
```

This will output something like the following:

```sh
                        user     system      total        real
Access Database:    0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.475375)
Access Redis:       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000037)

<------ 20 -------> # This is where the 20 comes in. NOTE: This is not shown in output.
```

*More information can be found [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-bm).*

Comment: I just came back to my own answer and was impressed (again) with how Benchmark handles this. Love Ruby.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer:  Because, as of Ruby 2.2, the `Benchmark` class uses a monotonic clock, as discussed in other answers.  See for instance the following source code, and look for "def measure" on line 286:  https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/lib/benchmark.rb

Answer (score 35):

Many of the answers suggest the use of `Time.now`. But it is worth being aware that `Time.now` can change. System clocks can drift and might get corrected by the system's administrator or via NTP. It is therefore possible for Time.now to jump forward or back and give your benchmarking inaccurate results.

A better solution is to use the operating system's monotonic clock, which is always moving forward. Ruby 2.1 and above give access to this via:

```
start = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
# code to time
finish = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
diff = finish - start # gets time is seconds as a float
```

You can read more details [here](https://archive.ph/DJ3VH). Also you can see popular Ruby project, Sidekiq, made the switch to [monotonic clock](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/commit/aa9745e9b29d408ac423356af50859cb9c382135).

Comment: Other units than seconds (ms, µs, ns, ...) are available, see [core doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Process#clock_gettime-instance_method)

Answer (score 10):

A second thought, define  the **measure()** function with Ruby code block argument can help simplify the time measure code:

```
def measure(&block)
  start = Time.now
  block.call
  Time.now - start
end

# t1 and t2 is the executing time for the code blocks.
t1 = measure { sleep(1) }

t2 = measure do
  sleep(2)
end
```

Comment: In your definition you call it `benchmark`. When you use it it is called `measure`. Please fix this.

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of [wquist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11406469), but a little simpler, you could also do it like below:

```
start = Time.now
# code to time
Time.now - start
```

Comment: This answer is a (slightly) different way to answer the question. Just because you could figure it out from @wquist's answer doesn't mean it isn't valid.