# Ruby on Rails' Method Benchmark Performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, benchmarking

I wonder what the benchmark for few rails methods would look like. Anyone got a website that can run custom methods?:

```
User.count
#=> 1000000 (Let's say about that)

u = User.where(account_id: 5)
u.count
#=> 100000

u.map |a| a.account_id = 6 end
```

Is there a way to test this sort of benchmark? How slow or fast is that iteration?

Comment: What do you try to achieve? There are faster ways in Rails to get the same results.

Comment: Trying to use best way possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure and Benchmark Time for Ruby Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406410/measure-and-benchmark-time-for-ruby-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ruby [benchmark module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) for this kind of test

```
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { User.count }
  x.report { u = User.where(account_id: 5); u.count }
  x.report { u = User.where(account_id: 5); u.map |a| a.account_id = 6 end }
end
```

Comment: Sweet. never knew about that!