# Is returning nil or a boolean at the end of a method more performant than letting Ruby return the result of the last line of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-management, garbage-collection, jruby

As we all know in Ruby, the last line of a method is the "returned" value of that method.

Let's say you have a procedure (aka, a method where we just want it to do work and do not care about the return value) that builds a heavy object, or its last line is a Rails logger statement or some other class instance.

Is it more performant (or consume less resources somehow), if you just add a "nil" or "boolean" to the last line instead of returning that heavy object when we don't use that return value?

```
def test_method
    some_big_object
end
```

vs

```
def test_method
    some_big_object
    nil # or true/false
end
```

In my mind, as far as pure object allocation, memory performance goes, the first option is better. Just because the method "returns" a big object that isn't used, doesn't mean it takes any further processing or causes any extra memory bloat.

The second option seems like it is actually ever so slightly worse due to the fact that it now creates one additional object.

I feel like adding the extra return line, especially if that return line is something other than nil, is redundant and wasteful. Surely Ruby's, and even JRUBY's, garbage collection is smarter than that?

I do realize there may be some benefit in returning nil to prevent other developers from trying to use this method to return a value when it is only meant to do work. But purely speaking of performance, am I correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails' Method Benchmark Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934638/ruby-on-rails-method-benchmark-performance)

Comment: I look forward to the day when my apps are at this level of performance optimization!

Comment: If this is a public method, I'd be a lot more worried about someone relying on an unintended return value than I would be about the performance loss or gain of creating or not creating a `nil` object, so much so that the performance question is irrelevant.

Comment: Good point. Deliberately returning `nil` allows you to someday think of the correct return value, so you can upgrade the method and return it without worrying about breaking any clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any method will return an object, or more specific: an object_id, which is just a number. Nil, false, some_big_object : all just a number. Don't bother.

Comment: You are close to answering the question, but have not completed answering it.

Comment: @sawa what do you mean? What has been left out?

Comment: The question in the title is "Is returning nil or a boolean at the end of a method more performant than letting Ruby return the result of the last line of code?" You gave clues to answer it, but have not answered it.

Comment: Based on what he stated, it sounds like the answer is "they are all just as performant at their base level. they all just return the ID of the object"